# Why does Bash have 2 ways to check for symbolic links (-h and -L)?

Tags: bash

**Why** does Bash provide both `-h` and `-L` to check if a file exists and is a symbolic link?

Comment: BTW, it's generally worth checking if something is specific to bash before asking about it as a bash question. Bash is (almost without exception) a superset of the POSIX sh language, which borrowed ideas from early ksh, which borrowed ideas from Bourne; there's a lot of history there, and checking whether what you're curious about is true through the history gives a very good idea of where something came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `-h` and `-L` are required by [the POSIX test standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). Thus, bash *must* include both to be compliant.

But... why? This is a historical question: Old versions of POSIX did not require a test operation for symlinks at all, a limitation rectified as recently as 2004 (with Issue 6). Prior to that, different UNIX implementations implemented this in mutually incompatible fashions; and the POSIX standard unified this difference by requiring both.

---

Notably, within modern BSD `test`, `-h` is documented as the legacy form, and `-L` its modern replacement. From [the FreeBSD man page for `test`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?test):

> `-h` *file*
>   True if *file*    exists and is a symbolic link.  This operator
>   is retained for compatibility with previous versions  of
>   this  program.  Do not rely on its existence; use `-L`
>    instead.